# extracting character strings from a vector of strings using regrex

Tags: r, string, character

I have the vector `files` which contains character strings like this one: `"./bNTI/bNTI_Yazoo_weighted.csv"` and I want to extract the name between the two `_` so in this example, "Yazoo".  I tried:

```
names <- gsub(".*_ (.+) _*", "\\1", files)
```

But that returned the exact same as the original `files` vector. Please help!

Comment: remove the space ie `gsub(".*_(.*)_.*", '\\1', files)`. There are no spaces in your names. Even if they ware, you do not need them in the regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Extract names between underscores

```
names <- gsub(".*/bNTI_(.*)_weighted\\.csv", "\\1", files)

# Print the extracted names
print(names)
```

- `.*` matches any character (except for a newline character) zero or more times.
- `/bNTI_` matches the literal "/bNTI_".
- `(.*)` captures any character (except for a newline character) zero or more times (this is the part you want to extract).
- `_weighted\\.csv` matches the literal " _weighted.csv".

By using `\\1` in the replacement part, you refer to the content captured by the parentheses in the pattern, which is the part between the underscores.

Comment: this is hardcoded. ie you cannot use it anywhere. eg `files <- c("./bNTI/bNTI_Yazoo_weighted.csv", "./bNTI2t/b_Yazoo2_weightedagain.csv")`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using `stringr`, making use of the look-behind `(?<=)` and look-ahead `(?=)` operators. Thus, the following regex looks for word characters (letters or numbers; `\\w`) with one or more characters (`+`) that is preceded by an underscore `(?<=_)` and followed by another underscore `(?=_)`.

```
library(stringr)

str_extract("./bNTI/bNTI_Yazoo_weighted.csv", "(?<=_)\\w+(?=_)")

# [1] "Yazoo"
```